# How can I sync my computer time with a specific website?

Tags: time, server, synchronization, pool, ntp

How can I sync my computer time with a specific website?
i want to my computer time is exactly same with this site:
http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=15131F

Answer (score 0):

You can only sync your computers to a specific server, if that server provides an interface (normally via ntp) to publish its clock's time. If the server you want to use doesn't provide such a service, then the best you can do is to sync your computer's clock to a public NTP server.
 One thing you could do is to ask the site's administrator whether the server is providing ntp services, or what public NTP server they are using to keep that server's clock in sync, and also sync your machine against that one.